# DocuSign Disable Signer ID Check

Tags: docusignapi

When we send an envelope to the Signer and when the signer opens the 'Review Document' link its asking to enter the personal information like home address etc.

We have selected the 'Disable recipient authentication for this account' under DocuSign account security settings as well.

But still DocuSign asking for ID Check.

[image: DocuSign Security settings]

Comment: If you're sending the envelope via the API then the ID check is specified there. Use DocuSign API logging and add (edit) your question to include the log

Comment: I've just deleted the templates and created again. Now its working. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

See the OP comment:

> I've just deleted the templates and created again. Now it's working.